# Python try-except exception syntax. A comma (',') is the same as 'as'

Tags: python, syntax, exception, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python try…except comma vs 'as' in except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except)

This question is so basic that I'm embarrassed to ask it.  However I've had trouble finding the answer online or in my python book and I hope I've worded and tagged this question well so that other people might benefit from the answers.

In python, a try-catch block looks like this:

```
try:
   do_Some_Stuff()
except ExceptionType as e:
   # Handle the error
```

I ran accross some code that seems to have a comma instead of the 'as'.  Is this the same thing?

```
try:
   do_Some_Stuff()
except ExceptionType, e:  # <-- comma(',') instead of 'as' here
   # Handle the error
```

Thanks in advance for not making me feel too stupid!

Comment: Yes, it's the same - but use as going forward :)

Comment: @YujiTomita: Of course, comma is more backwards-compatible.