# What's wrong with my except?

Tags: python, exception, syntax-error, except

I've got a SyntaxError on my except:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'P:D:H:d:u:p:nvhmJi:c:Ml:TB:',
            ['host=', 'port=', 'directory=', 'user=', 'password=',
             'daemon=', 'noauth', 'help', 'verbose', 'mysql', 
             'icounter=', 'config=', 'nolock', 'nomime', 'loglevel', 'noiter',
             'baseurl='])
except getopt.GetoptError, e:
    print usage
    print '>>>> ERROR: %s' % str(e)
    sys.exit(2)
```

I get the error:

```
File "main.py", line 199

except getopt.GetoptError, e:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try `except getopt.GetoptError as e` ?

Comment: Check out this discussion regarding the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except

Answer (score 59):

You use python3 and in python3 [the raise syntax no longer accepts comma-separated arguments](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html).

Use `as` instead:

```
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
```

This form is also backwards-compatible with 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: I'd add that if the OP wants code that's compatible with python<2.6 then he should use `except getopt.GetoptError:` and then retrieve the error information using `sys.exc_info()`

Answer (score 9):

Your syntax is invalid for catching the exception

You should have written `except getopt.GetoptError as e:`  instead of `except getopt.GetoptError, e:`

Comment: This was the correct syntax in earlier versions of Python, though.