# How to avoid a syntax error when trying to run the sequencing analysis package ScaleHD

Tags: python, macos, terminal, repeat, fastq

I'd like to use ScaleHD to analyse some Illumina amplicon sequencing of a trinucleotide repeat region.

https://scalehd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

https://pypi.org/project/ScaleHD/

I’m using a conda environment in MacOS and installed ScaleHD using `pip install scalehd`. I think I’ve installed all the dependencies suggested by the developer. But when I try to run it I get a syntax error.

```
$ ScaleHD -v -c ~/analysis/ScaleHD/config_mf.xml -j "hello_documentation" -o ~/analysis/ScaleHD/output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelflower/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioinfo/bin/ScaleHD", line 5, in <module>
from ScaleHD.sherpa import main
  File "/Users/michaelflower/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioinfo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ScaleHD/sherpa.py", line 115
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(bioinfo)
```

I’ve read around a bit and seen it could be a problem with how the ScaleHD.sherpa file has written the ‘except’ – [What's wrong with my except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908789/whats-wrong-with-my-except). But I'm not sure what can be done about it?

I’ve provided sample R1 and R2 fastq file, the config file and reference files I’m using here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvBi5ipmBYfrhbRIKPYjfyk5th5uAQ?e=PYdrbG

Here’s how I’ve set up the directory:

```
$ tree analysis/ScaleHD/
analysis/ScaleHD/
|-- config.xml
|-- config_mf.xml
|-- data_dir
|   |-- ciosi41CAG_S4_L001_R1_001.fastq
|   `-- ciosi41CAG_S4_L001_R2_001.fastq
|-- output
`-- ref
    |-- 4k-HD-INTER.fa
    `-- 4k-HD-Reverse.fasta
```

I'd be very grateful for any help getting this up and running. Thanks!

Comment: You need a version which is compatible with python 3.

Comment: Or, conversely, use Python 2 to run it. According to the doco, version 1.0 should be tested with Python 3.7; did you install an older version?

Comment: What does the code look like after the except statement? If it uses 'e' then the line should probably read 'except Exception as e:'. If 'e' isn't used then 'except Exception:' will suffice

Comment: @AndyKnight It is inadvisable to suggest to a novice that migrating a third-party library module from Python 2 to Python 3 is a simple matter. If the code has one leftover from Python ≤2.4, it very likely has many others, some of them trickier to fix for someone unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: @AndyKnight, here is the full text in the ScaleHD file: '#!/Users/michaelflower/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioinfo/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from ScaleHD.sherpa import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
'

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'll try and find out which version my 'pip' command installed. Unfortunately I can't even run a version check command as I get the same syntax error as above. @tripleee, could I please ask how to run it in python2? I've tried putting python2 ahead of the full ScaleHD ... command above, but get '$ python2 scalehd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'scalehd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(bioinfo) '.

Comment: If you are on a Mac, `/usr/bin/python` should be Python 2.7. But you will probably have to `pip install` the package for this Python version separately (preferably in a new virtual environment).

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm making progress. I built a new python2 conda environment, as suggested here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/. I'm now getting ScaleHD running, though still have to work out how to assign information in the way it needs. But at least the syntax problem is solved!

Comment: '$ ScaleHD -v -c ~/analysis/ScaleHD/config_mf.xml -j "hello_documentation" -o ~/analysis/ScaleHD/output
shd__ ScaleHD: Automated DNA micro-satellite genotyping.
shd__ alastair.maxwell@glasgow.ac.uk

shd__ Creating Output with prefix: hello_documentation
shd__ XML Config: Specified data directory could not be found.
shd__ XML Config: Specified forward reference file could not be found.
shd__ XML Config: Specified reverse reference file could not be found.
shd__ XML Config: Failure, exiting.
(py2) 
'