# Catch exception gets UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

I wrote a crawler to fetch information out of an Q&A website. Since not all the fields are presented in a page all the time, I used multiple try-excepts to handle the situation.

```
def answerContentExtractor( loginSession, questionLinkQueue , answerContentList) :
    while True:
        URL = questionLinkQueue.get()
        try:
            response   = loginSession.get(URL,timeout = MAX_WAIT_TIME)
            raw_data   = response.text

            #These fields must exist, or something went wrong...
            questionId = re.findall(REGEX,raw_data)[0]
            answerId   = re.findall(REGEX,raw_data)[0]
            title      = re.findall(REGEX,raw_data)[0]

        except requests.exceptions.Timeout ,IndexError:
            print >> sys.stderr, URL + " extraction error..."
            questionLinkQueue.task_done()
            continue

        try:
            questionInfo = re.findall(REGEX,raw_data)[0]
        except IndexError:
            questionInfo = ""

        try:
            answerContent = re.findall(REGEX,raw_data)[0]
        except IndexError:
            answerContent = ""

        result = {
                  'questionId'   : questionId,
                  'answerId'     : answerId,
                  'title'        : title,
                  'questionInfo' : questionInfo,
                  'answerContent': answerContent
                  }

        answerContentList.append(result)
        questionLinkQueue.task_done()
```

And this code, sometimes, may or may not, gives the following exception during runtime:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'IndexError' referenced before assignment
```

The line number indicates the error occurs at the second `except IndexError:`

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, Would love to give the marks that you deserve, too bad I can only mark one as the correct answer...

Comment: Typos, I hand typed it to striped some un-needed lines.. Edited already..

Comment: Related: [multiple exceptions in one line (except block)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block?rq=1)

Comment: The specific issue here is 2.x-specific, since in 3.x [the `as` keyword must be used to capture the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.x, the line

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout, IndexError:
```

[is equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/)

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as IndexError:
```

Thus, the exception caught by `requests.exceptions.Timeout` is assigned to `IndexError`. A simpler example:

```
try:
    true
except NameError, IndexError:
    print IndexError
    #name 'true' is not defined
```

To catch multiple exceptions, [put the names in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428):

```
except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, IndexError):
```

Later, an `UnboundLocalError` [can occur because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/) the assignment to `IndexError` makes it a local variable (shadowing the builtin name):

```
>>> 'IndexError' in answerContentExtractor.func_code.co_varnames
True
```

So, if `requests.exceptions.Timeout` was *not* raised, `IndexError` will not have been (incorrectly) defined when the code attempts `except IndexError:`.

Again, a simpler example:

```
def func():
    try:
        func # defined, so the except block doesn't run,
    except NameError, IndexError: # so the local `IndexError` isn't assigned
        pass
    try:
        [][1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
func()
#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'IndexError' referenced before assignment
```

In 3.x, the problem will occur (after fixing the `except` syntax, which makes the error more obvious) *even if* the first exception is caught. This is because the local name `IndexError` will then [be explicitly `del`d after the first `try`/`except` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271752).

Comment: It solved the problem.. Thank you for explaining all the stuffs behind the scene.. I got a much better sense about the code other than just fixing the error.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout ,IndexError:
```

Python will except `requests.exceptions.Timeout` error and the error object will be `IndexError`. It should have been something like this

```
except (requests.exceptions.Timeout ,IndexError) as e:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout ,IndexError:
```

means same as `except requests.exceptions.Timeout as IndexError`

You should use

```
except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, IndexError):
```

instead