# Passing arguments to decorator from decorated function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have prepared some function decorator with default argument passed from decorator point of view:

```
def decorator_wraper(max_repeating=20)
    def decorator(function):
        def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"max_repeating = {max_repeating}")
            repeat = 0
            while repeat < max_repeating:
                try:
                    return function(*args, **kwargs)
                    break
                except Exception:
                    pass
                repeat += 1
        return wrap_function
    return decorator
```

It works ok, so if some decorated function fails - decorator allows to repeat the function until success or repeat >= max_repeating.

But what if I will need to change the default max_repeating from decorated function point of view?

Here I have two decorated functions:

```
@decorator_wraper(5)
def decorate_me_with_argument(max_repeating=10):
    print('decorate_me_with_argument')

@decorator_wraper()
def decorate_me_with_default():
    print('decorate_me_with_default')

calling:
decorate_me_with_argument() # max_repeating should be 5 cause while decorating the function I have passed 5.
decorate_me_with_default() # max repeating should be 20 cause default for the decorator is 20.
```

And what I want to achieve:

```
decorate_me_with_argument(3) # max_repeating should be 3
decorate_me_with_default(8) # max repeating should be 8
```

Maybe is there any simple method to solve something like this?

Comment: Any arguments you pass to `decorate_me_with_argument` are now going to `wrap_function`, what if the wrapped `function` also takes arguments?

Comment: I have forced all arguments as key-args and it's working for me. (I mean solution what big_bad_bison proposed)
Maybe do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make the first argument for `wrap_function` the number of repeats with the default value of `max_repeats` specified in the decorator.

```
def decorator_wraper(max_repeats=20):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrap_function(max_repeating=max_repeats, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f"max_repeating = {max_repeating}")
            repeat = 0
            while repeat < max_repeating:
                try:
                    return function(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception:
                    pass
        return wrap_function
    return decorator


@decorator_wraper(5)
def decorate_me_with_argument():
    print('decorate_me_with_argument')


@decorator_wraper()
def decorate_me_with_default():
    print('decorate_me_with_default')


decorate_me_with_argument()  # max_repeating = 5
decorate_me_with_default()  # max_repeating = 20
decorate_me_with_argument(3)  # max_repeating = 3
decorate_me_with_default(8)  # max_repeating = 8
```

Comment: Really like the solution!

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do this is to expose the number of repeats on the `wrap_function`:

```
def decorator_wrapper(max_repeating=20):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"max_repeating = {wrap_function.max_repeating}")
            for _ in range(wrap_function.max_repeating):
                try:
                    return function(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception:
                    pass
        wrap_function.max_repeating = max_repeating
        return wrap_function
    return decorator
```

That way you don't change the interface of the wrapped `function`, but you can still change the repeat limit after the initial decoration:

```
>>> @decorator_wrapper()
... def bad_func():
...     print("in bad func")
...     raise Exception("oh no!")
...
>>> bad_func.max_repeating
20
>>> bad_func.max_repeating = 3
>>> bad_func()
max_repeating = 3
in bad func
in bad func
in bad func
```

Adding arbitrary attributes to `wrap_function` would also allow you to provide an inline API for calling the wrapped function with a different number of retries, e.g. something like:

```
bad_func.retry_times(3)()
```

Again `bad_func.retry_times(3)` is a drop-in replacement for `bad_func` as it returns a function that accepts exactly the same arguments, rather than adding to (and risking clashing with) the wrapped function's existing parameters.

---

Note you should probably raise the error if the last retry fails, or it will get lost entirely:

```
def retry(times, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(times):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            exception = exc
    raise exception
```

`exception = exc` is needed because [except-clause deletes local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24271752/3001761).

Comment: Oh yeah, of course repeat += 1 should be in the decorator.

Comment: @tomm I switched from the `while` loop to a `for`, so you don't need the `repeat` variable at all.

Comment: It's really interesting what did you add above. I have just some question to the above.
What did you mean while adding an example "bad_func.retry_times(3)()"?
How to use it?

Comment: @tomm 1. in your current implementation if the function fails _every time_ it's retried, the wrapper just silently returns and the error can't be handled; 2. I mean rather than adding a `max_repeating` attribute that's an integer, you could add a `retry_times` attribute that's a function. And that _is_ how to use it, you call the attribute to get a function with the right number of retries then call that function with whatever arguments are needed.

Answer (score -1):

Following is similar to what I have in my project, the `kwargs` param takes all what are passed from the decorated function:

```
def decorator_wraper(func):
    def wrap_function(max_repeating=20, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('max_repeating'):
            max_repeating = kwargs['max_repeating']
        print(max_repeating)
        # TODO
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function

@decorator_wraper
def decorate_me():
    pass

decorate_me()  # should print 20
decorate_me(max_repeating=10)  # should print 10
```

Comment: `max_repeating` is the first _positional_ argument to `wrap_function`, so if you decorated a function with any positional parameters you'd never be able to call it _without_ setting `max_repeating`.