# how to best filter exceptions on their __cause__ (or __context__)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Given a base exception type:

```
class MyModuleError(Exception):
    pass
```

Suppose we have code that explicitly raises it, using exception chaining:

```
def foo():
    try:
        #some code
    except (ZeroDivisionError, OSError) as e:
        raise MyModuleError from e
```

Now, in the calling code...

```
try:
    foo()
except MyModuleError as e:
    # Now what?
```

how can I idiomatically write the `except` clause, so that the exception handling depends on the `__cause__` (chained exception)?

I thought of these approaches:

a) using `type(e)` like:

```
    # filter here
    t=type(e.__cause__)
    if t is ZeroDivisionError:
        doStuff()
    elif t is OSError:
        doOtherStuff()
    else:
        raise
```

b) using `isinstance()` like:

```
    # filter here
    if isinstance(e.__cause__, ZeroDivisionError):
        doStuff()
    elif isinstance(e.__cause__, OSError):
        doOtherStuff()
    else:
        raise
```

c) re-raising like:

```
    # filter here
    try:
        raise e.__cause__
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        doStuff()
    except OSError:
        doOtherStuff()
    except:
        raise e    #which should be the "outer" exception
```

Comment: Option b) seems best to me.  a) doesn't account for subtypes, and c) puts extra junk in the traceback

Comment: I just noted, that method `wrapper3` seems to have a memory leek (which I don't understand why)... If I call it with `-n 100000000`, the python process eats up the whole system memory (62GB) until the kernel kills it ^^

Comment: @wim. Was about to say the same thing

Comment: @wim That with the subtype I don't understand, If I take e.g. `PermissionError` which is derived from `OSError`, then both (a) and (b) seem to always give true identity only (`PermissionError is OSError`, `OSError is PermissionError`, `isinstance(PermissionError, OSError)` and `isinstance(OSError, PermissionError)` are all `False`)

Comment: Edit: Stupid me... need to take concrete instances, of course. Then `isinstance()` considers the subtyps.

Comment: Yeah for two types you want `issubclass(PermissionError, OSError)` not isinstance.

Comment: Basically, (a) and (b) are the two reasonable ones here, depending on precisely the semantics you want for the runtime type checking (checking precisely the type or using `isinstance` which accounts for subtypes (and overriden instance checks e.g. from `__subclasshook__`, although taht is more of an edge case)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that would be the chosen answer for this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The re-raising is not recommended. In general, it is not idiomatic to raise something deliberately so that it can be immediately caught<sup>1</sup>. It's also less performant (exception handling can involve quite a bit of overhead when the exception is actually raised), and creates a reference cycle between the exception object and the current stack frame, which in the reference implementation of Python will leak memory when the auxiliary garbage collector is disabled. (This is why [exception names created with `as` are explicitly deleted after the `except` block in 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271752/).)

On general principle, `isinstance` [is the preferred means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580) of type-checking rather than comparing `type` results directly, because `isinstance` automatically takes subtyping into account. The normal functionality of `except` accounts for subtyping (e.g. `except IOError:` will catch a `FileNotFoundError`, which is normally desirable); it stands to reason that, in any normal circumstance, type-checking of the chained exception should do this as well.

There is no explicit built-in functionality for this; therefore, approach b) is recommended here.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Yes, `for` loops [are internally implemented this way, using `StopIteration`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413969). That's an implementation detail, and user code isn't intended to look like it's doing such things.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

At least the performance part of my question can be answered quite easily.

Assuming the following example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import timeit
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
parser.add_argument("-n", "--iterations", type=int, default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()



class MyModuleError(Exception):
    pass

def foo():
    try:
        f = 1/0
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
        raise MyModuleError from e

def wrapper1():
    try:
        foo()
    except MyModuleError as e:
        t = type(e.__cause__)
        if t is ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        elif t is OSError:
            pass
        else:
           raise

def wrapper2():
    try:
        foo()
    except MyModuleError as e:
        if isinstance(e.__cause__, ZeroDivisionError):
            pass
        elif isinstance(e.__cause__, OSError):
            pass
        else:
           raise

def wrapper3():
    try:
        foo()
    except MyModuleError as e:
        try:
            raise e.__cause__
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
        except OSError:
            pass
        except:
           raise e    #which should be the "outer" exception



t = timeit.timeit(wrapper1, number=args.iterations)
print(f"wrapper1: {t}")
t = timeit.timeit(wrapper2, number=args.iterations)
print(f"wrapper2: {t}")
t = timeit.timeit(wrapper3, number=args.iterations)
print(f"wrapper3: {t}")
```

Gives, as of CPython 3.11.4 the following results:

```
$ ./chained-exception-handling.py -n 10000000
wrapper1: 4.373930287983967
wrapper2: 4.534742605988868
wrapper3: 7.319078870001249
```

Actually, I'm a bit disappointed... I thought the method of re-raising the inner exception might be the most "pythonic" one, but that's also the slowest (will, kinda fits Python, doesn't it?! O;-) ).

Comment: See my own comment to the original question.. `wrapper3` (for some reason I don't understand) has a memory leak and gets the process killed by the kernel if `-n` is sufficiently high.

Comment: re-raising an exception to purposefully catch it is certainly *not* pythonic.

Comment: So, when you catch an exception, the error carries around a reference to the stack frame, but the stack frame references the error.  This causes a reference cycle which can lead to memory leaks. Normally, as a special case, the `e` reference is actually deleted, but re-raising it like that keeps it alive. CPython uses reference counting as its main memory-management strategy, but there is an auxiliary gc that handles references cycles, but I'm pretty that `timeit.timeit` disables the `gc`! So this would explain the memory leak

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So... you'd say this is not really a bug - or should I report it upstream?

Comment: This is not a CPython bug, no. I suspect it's just an issue with `timeit.timeit`, but it isn't a bug there either, since the fact that it disables the auxiliary garbage collector [is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit). One thing to test would be running `wrapper3()` in a loop outside of timeit and seeing if a sufficiently high n reproduces the out of memory error.

Comment: Or alternatively, as the docs suggest, add `'gc.enable()'` as the `setup` string