# Getting the Python exception object in a call

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the exception object without relying on the namespace of the except block?

```
try:
   destined_to_fail()
except Exception as e:
   other_function()

def other_function():
   # can I get e here, without passing it as an argument?
```

Comment: It's not possible to use the name `e` itself, though you can bind the object to a different name: see explanation here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271752/why-do-i-get-a-nameerror-or-unboundlocalerror-from-using-a-named-exception

Comment: If `other_function` expects access to an exception, it would probably be simpler for it to accept it as an optional argument.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can get the exception using `sys.exception()`:

```py
import sys

def other_function():
    exc = sys.exception()
    print("exception was:", type(exc), exc)

try:
   raise KeyError('this is a test')
except Exception:
   other_function()
```

Running the above code produces:

```
exception was: <class 'KeyError'> 'this is a test'
```