# How can I figure whether to have e in "except urllib2.URLError, e"

Tags: python, exception

I got this code while I was looking into urllib2.

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.baibai.com')
try: urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError,e: 
    print e.reason
```

I got confused when and whether to use `e` in the statement `except urllib2.URLError, e:` since it seems OK to use `except urllib2.URLError:` (without `e`).

Can every `except` statement have the format `except:XXXX, e` or just in some cases?

Comment: if you are not going to do something with the "e" then don't have it. Here you are printing e.reason, so it's useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the syntax `urllib2.URLError, e` you have access to the exception that was thrown (for example to print the message). If you only use `except urllib2.URLError` you indicate that you want to do something when a `URLError` is thrown, but you don't need the actual exception object.

Note that you are using a outdated python version because you are using `,` in your `except` blocks. Python 3+ requires `as` instead of `,` (`except urllib2.URLError as e`) while only Python 2.5- uses the `,` syntax.

I recommend you learn a bit about exceptions. [Here's the official documentation on exceptions.](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/errors.html) More information about `,` vs `as` can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except) StackOverflow answer.