# CasperJS does not work in Cron when called from PHP script

Tags: php, cron, phantomjs, cpanel, casperjs

As a test, I have the following PHP sript:

```
<?php
  print shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js --ssl-protocol=any --verbose");
?>
```

The casperjs script is the following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

I would expect an output like:

```
CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS
PhantomJS | PhantomJS
```

This actually works fine in commandline. However, I need to run a PHP script that calls a CasperJS script in a Cronjob.

```
PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs php /path/to/file/test.php
```

Somehow, when I do that, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/casperjs", line 138
except OSError as err:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.21
Content-type: text/html
```

I have tried to set the environment variable for PhantomJS, but it does not help. I stripped down my own script to the above to ensure that this error has nothing to do with my own coding.

Anybody any idea how to get CasperJS working in a PHP script from a Cronjob?

BTW: I use CentOS.

Comment: Why `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs php /path/to/file/test.php`? Have you tried with `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`?

Comment: I tried with and without the PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE. Some have suggested that this might be a solution, but it did not help...

Comment: I don't mean without. You simply have a wrong executable definition. `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs php /path/to/file/test.php` is not PhantomJS, but rather some kind of php file.

Comment: Ah :-) The file that I call is a PHP file, as that PHP file contains a shell_exec to the casperjs script. so, the base cronjob would be php /path/to/file/test.php

Comment: My guess is that you should pass absolute path to your `test.js`

Comment: Sadly, I tried that also, but it did not work. I also tried running under root account the cronjob, but no solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same error, because my machine has installed some versions of python. So you should install python 2.6+ or edit `/usr/local/bin/casperjs`. Thanks

from

```
OSError as err:
```

to

```
OSError, err:
```

[Python try...except comma vs 'as' in except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except)