# Python, distinguishing custom exceptions

Tags: python, exception

fairly new to Python here. Have this code:

```
def someFunction( num ):
    if num < 0:
        raise Exception("Negative Number!")
    elif num > 1000:
        raise Exception("Big Number!")
    else:
        print "Tests passed"


try:
    someFunction(10000)
except Exception:
    print "This was a negative number but we didn't crash"
except Exception:
    print "This was a big number but we didn't crash"
else:
    print "All tests passed and we didn't crash"
```

I originally used `raise "Negative Number!"` etc but quickly discovered that this was the old way of doing things and you have to call the Exception class. Now it's working fine but how do I distinguish between my two exceptions? For the code below it's printing "This was a negative number but we didn't crash". Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: You wouldn't normally raise `Exception`, but some subclass of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to create your own exception classes if you want to be able to distinguish the kind of exception that happened. example (i inherited from `ValueError` as i think this is the closest to what you want - it also allows you to just catch `ValueError` should the distinction not matter):

```
class NegativeError(ValueError):
    pass

class BigNumberError(ValueError):
    pass

def someFunction( num ):
    if num < 0:
        raise NegativeError("Negative Number!")
    elif num > 1000:
        raise BigNumberError("Big Number!")
    else:
        print "Tests passed"

try:
    someFunction(10000)
except NegativeError as e:
    print "This was a negative number but we didn't crash"
    print e
except BigNumberError as e:
    print "This was a big number but we didn't crash"
    print e
else:
    print "All tests passed and we didn't crash"
```

Comment: [Use `except ... as ...` instead of `except ..., ...`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2535770/2846140)

Comment: Thanks for this, great solution. Is NegativeError as e equivalent to NegativeError, e ?

Comment: @Kex,  `NegativeError as e` will work for python2 and 3

Comment: in python 2.7 it is (i think...); python 3 will only accept the syntax with `as`.