# How to catch this specific Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-3.3

I'm creating an instance of a Class like this :

```
def exists(username, password):
    try:
        user_doc =  User.objects(username=username,password=password).exclude('password')
    except DoesNotExist, e:
        raise e
    return user_doc._parse()
```

The `try` block raises this exception when there are no matching records.
 But I get syntax error.

How should I catch this exception ?

Comment: I also want to catch this error at the place from where I'm calling this function exists.

Comment: Python version? Use `as e` rather than `,e`, the latter form has been deprecated and removed in Python 3.

Comment: @mystikacid So what's the error?

Comment: And maybe you could try `except DoesNotExist as e: print(e)`

Comment: Check this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/2535770/3681882