# Catching all Custom Exceptions Python

Tags: python

I have a number of custom exceptions created for my Django project. like so

**errors.py**

```
# General Exceptions

class VersionError(Exception):
    pass

class ParseError(Exception):
    pass

class ConfigError(Exception):
    pass

class InstallError(Exception):
    pass
```

However I want to print the output from my custom exceptions but not the general. But do not want to list them all out, i.e

```
try:
   do something wrong
except <custom errors>, exc:
    print exc
except:
    print "Gen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical way would be to create common superclass for all your exceptions.

```
# General Exceptions
class MyAppError(Exception):
    pass

class VersionError(MyAppError):
    pass

class ParseError(MyAppError):
    pass

class ConfigError(MyAppError):
    pass

class InstallError(MyAppError):
    pass
```

With this inheritance three you may simply catch all exceptions of type `MyAppError`.

```
try:
    do_something()
except MyAppError as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a tuple of the exceptions:

```
my_exceptions = (VersionError,
                 ParseError,
                 ConfigError,
                 InstallError)
```

Usage:

```
except my_exceptions as exception:
    print exception
```

e.g:

```
>>> my_exceptions = (LookupError, ValueError, TypeError)
>>> try:
...     int('a')
... except my_exceptions as exception:
...     print type(exception)
...     print exception
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a custom marker base class for your custom exceptions:

```
# General Exceptions
class MyException(Exception):
    """Just a marker base class"""

class VersionError(MyException):
    pass

class ParseError(MyException):
    pass

class ConfigError(MyException):
    pass

class InstallError(MyException):
    pass
```

With that modification, you can then easily say:

```
try:
   do something wrong
except MyException as exc:
    print exc
except:
    print "Some other generic exception was raised"
```

(BTW, you should use the recommended `except Exception as ex` syntax instead of the `except Exception, ex`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except) for details)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a common base class for all your custom exceptions, and catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom base exception and derive all the other custom exceptions form this base execption:

```
class CustomBaseException(Exception):
    pass

# General Exceptions

class VersionError(CustomBaseException):
    pass

class ParseError(CustomBaseException):
    pass

class ConfigError(CustomBaseException):
    pass

class InstallError(CustomBaseException):
    pass
```

Then you can do

```
try:
   do something wrong
except CustomBaseExecption, exc:
    print exc
except:
    print "Gen
```