# error in python install module

Tags: python, module, syntax-error

I need to install a module `txsckjs`,but when I run `pip install txsockjs` it shows me some error and I don't know what happened.

The error is following:

```
(venv)lk@linux-7hhe:~/MyImprove/project> pip install txsockjs
Collecting txsockjs
  Using cached txsockjs-1.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-5pxhyr0u/txsockjs/setup.py", line 73
        except Exception, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5pxhyr0u/txsockjs/
```

Comment: Which is the python version you are using?

Comment: Seems you are using Python3, where this syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the version of Python you are using is not compatible with the given module.

[image]

I have Python 3.5.2 and was able to reporduce your error. It should work on Python 2 I suppose.

Comment: Thanks a lot！I will do a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `except Exception, e` with `except Exception as e` in txsockjs/setup.py.

As underlined by SilentMonk and Saket, Python version matters in this case. See [Python try…except comma vs 'as' in except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except) and the reference, [PEP 3110 -- Catching Exceptions in Python 3000](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#grammar-changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot. ohoh