# newbie using pyalgotrade and yahoofinance

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I am trying to use `yahoofinance.build_feed` from pyalgotrade (version 0.18) to build a cvs file containing OHLC data. I have no clue why I get this error. Thank you for any help.

---

```
from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance

instruments = ["orcl"]

feed = yahoofinance.build_feed(instruments, 2010, 2015, './csv', 86400, timezone=None, skipErrors=True)
```

---

Unfortunately, the error I got is

---

```
>>> runfile('/home/marco/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='/home/marco/.config/spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/marco/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance
  File "/home/marco/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyalgotrade/tools/yahoofinance.py", line 119
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Thanks, Marco.

Comment: The `pyalgotrade.tools` that you're using is old code, written for Python 2 using obsolete syntax and doesn't work without rewriting on Python 3.

Comment: Thank you Antti, do you know what library could be close to pyalgotrade on Python 3 ?

Comment: No, I have no idea about the library, I just translated those error messages into English.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2535770/956660

Comment: You want [zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline).

Answer (score -1):

Try it using Python 2.7 Python 2.7 is stable compared to Python 3.4