# Does pyramid_simpleform work with python3.5.2?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm writing an application using the pyramid framework using python 3.5.2, and when I import pyramid_simpleform, this error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/someuser/dir/sub_dir/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/pyramid_simpleform/__init__.py", line 175
    except Invalid, e:
                  ^
```

Is the python version not compatible with this library? (I believe I downloaded the 0.61 version of pyramid_simpleform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the error thrown it seems like the library you have downloaded is using old Python 2 syntax for catching errors, according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535770/5695018). Hence probably being incompatible with Python 3.

It seems however that there is a newer development version of this library available for download from the official Python website [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_simpleform/0.7.dev0); version 0.7.dev0, which is apparently compatible with  Python 3.