# pserve development.ini --reload: fails in windows 10 64bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, reload

I am following [an article](http://www.brettdangerfield.com/post/creating_a_blog_with_pyramid_mongdb_bootstrap/) and creating my first project,

while i try the below command; the process gets into a loop and starts a server and kills it and again starts a server and kills and it keeps doing this continuously without breaking the loop and exiting.

```
pserve development.ini --reload
```

Below is the log

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
Starting monitor for PID 11912.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\hupper\ipc.py", line 322, in spawn_main

    func(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\hupper\worker.py", line 237, in worker_main

    func(*spec_args, **spec_kwargs)
  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 32, in main

    return command.run()
  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 229, in run

    app = loader.get_wsgi_app(app_name, config_vars)
  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\plaster_pastedeploy\__init__.py", line 131, in get_wsgi_app
    global_conf=defaults)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 450, in get_context
    global_additions=global_additions)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 562, in _pipeline_app_context
    for name in pipeline[:-1]]

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 562, in <listcomp>
    for name in pipeline[:-1]]

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)

  File "d:\others\python\myblog\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))

  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2405, in load
    return self.resolve()

  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2411, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)

  File "D:\Others\Python\myBlog\lib\site-packages\weberror-0.13.1-py3.6.egg\weberror\evalexception.py", line 127
    except ValueError, ve:
                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Killing server with PID 11912.

Starting monitor for PID 4564.

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the library you're trying to use isn't built for Python 3. The `except SomeException, v:` syntax is only valid in Python 2. In Python 3 you must use `except SomeException as v:`. Try running this with Python 2 or finding a newer version of this library that supports Python 3.

[Python try...except comma vs 'as' in except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except)