# Why config is not working in python3.5/dist-packages/config.py

Tags: python

```
import config as regex

    except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Issue in Calcutaing: '+str(e))
    return None
```

I want to execute this program but it gives the following error.

```
    import config as regex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/config.py", line 733
    except Exception, e:
                ^
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Comment: @noteness Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 the line

```
except Exception, e:
```

[must be written as](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535760/35070)

```
except Exception as e:
```

Likely, if you want your module to be published, you should also give it a more descriptive name than `config`.

Comment: I am already using except Exception as e:,  How I give more descriptive name?

Comment: Are you sure? Your error message says otherwise. If you want to install a package, either move and install it to a subdirectory (so it ends up getting installed as `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myproject/config.py`), or, if it should be a top-level module, rename it to a unique name (`jaysconfig.py`).

Comment: Yes, I already install it, there is no any myproject directory, if i build it then it shows access denied.