# Can I use ',' instead of 'as' python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm using a code in python 3 that was written in python 2 syntax. 
The code have the right libraries and everything is working fine but this gives me an error:

```
        except Exception, _hx_e:
        _hx_e1 = _hx_e.val if isinstance(_hx_e, _HxException) else _hx_e
        e = _hx_e1
        tmp = None
```

Is there a way to use this `,` python 2 annotation instead of `as` in python 3?

Comment: Why not use the right syntax? You should also attempt to switch your python2 to python3, as python2's end of life is weeks away https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python try...except comma vs 'as' in except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except)

Comment: Answer: no, you can't.

Comment: @RichardStoeffel I'm using a library for school project that they made... don't ask me why they are doing this... I guess that they made this library in the past and didn't updated it

Comment: :( @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @AsafH I'm currently porting a very complex and quite huge codebase to Python3 so I can feel your pain. But facts are facts and your only solution here is to to port this code to Python3 (assuming you need it to run on python3 of course, but py2 is almost dead, really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old syntax is no longer valid.

[Source](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html#the-new-except-syntax)

> In Python 2, the syntax for catching exceptions was **except
>   ExceptionType:**, or **except ExceptionType, target:** when the exception
>   object is desired. **ExceptionType** can be a tuple, as in, for example,
>   **except (TypeError, ValueError):**.
>
> This could result in hard-to-spot bugs: the command **except TypeError,
>   ValueError:** (note lack of parentheses) will only handle **TypeError**. It
>   will also assign the exception object to the name **ValueError**,
>   shadowing the built-in.
>
> To fix this, Python 2.6 introduced an alternate syntax: **except
>   ExceptionType as target:**. ***In Python 3, the old syntax is no longer
>   allowed***.
>
> You will need to switch to the new syntax. The recommended fixer works
>   quite reliably, and it also fixes the Iterating Exceptions problem
>   described below.