# Is there anything wrong with my python code in line 56?

Tags: python, twitter

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNhOy.png)

hi, I am trying to run this python code for twitter **scraping**. as it is shown in the screenshot, it gives me a syntax error that I can't figure out. here is the whole code:

```
print ('Filtering the public timeline for track="%s"' % (q,))

twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter_api.auth)

stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track=q)

for tweet in stream:
    try:
        if tweet['truncated']:
            tweet_text = tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text']
        else:
            tweet_text = tweet['text']
        # write the values to file
        csvwriter.writerow([
            tweet['created_at'],
            getVal(tweet['user']['screen_name']),
            getVal(tweet_text),
            getVal(tweet['user']['location']),
            tweet['user']['statuses_count'],
            tweet['user']['followers_count'],
            tweet['user']['friends_count'],
            tweet['user']['created_at']
            ])
        # print something to the screen, mostly so we can see what is going on...
        print (tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'), tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'))
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        pass
```

Comment: For Python 3, try `except Exception as err:` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you are running this using `Python 3` and not `2`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535760/python-try-except-comma-vs-as-in-except) explains that the format you've used for the `except` statement would be wrong in that case.

The TL;DR of that post is:

switch the comma to `as`: `except Exception as err:`